# Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $a, b,$ and $k$ such that $k = \frac{2a + b^2 + b + 1}{a^2 + ab}.$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Part A: Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $a, b,$ and $k$ such that 
>   $$k = \frac{2a + b^2 + b + 1}{a^2 + ab}.$$
>   Part B: Prove $k = 3$ for all integers $a$ and $b$ found in part A.

I have discovered a recursive formula that generates infinitely many solutions (which is PART A). However, I don't know how to approach PART B. The recursive formula I discovered is: 
$a_1 = 1$, 
$b_1 = 0$, 
$a_2 = 3$, 
$b_2 = 10$, 
$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} - 1$, 
$b_n = a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Could you, uh, type out your attempts at factorising the expression?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have discovered a recursive formula that generates infinitely many solutions (which is PART A).  However, I don't know how to approach PART B.
The recursive formula I discovered is:
a(1) = 1, b(1) = 1
a(2) = 3, b(2) = 1     
a(n) = 5a(n-1) - a(n-2) - 1      b(n) = a(n-1)

Comment: On Math SE, it's always a good idea to include your work. Otherwise, a bare post can be interpreted as laziness and that is taken unfavorably here. Please [edit] your post to include any relevant information, like your work. It's best if you can also type it up properly. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: When k = 3, completing the squares of a and b form a Pell equation and is a way to generate infinitely many solutions in a closed form.  This is not what I'm interested in.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Do you know [Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping)?

Comment: Vieta root jumping is how I was able to derive the recursive formula.  This problem results from:
Finding all positive integers x, y, and z such that:
x^2 + y^2 + x + y + 1 = xyz.
CASE 1: x = y
the resulting equation yields z = 5.
CASE 2: y > x   → y = x + n for some integer n.
substitution and solving for z we have:
z = 2 + {2x + n^2 + n + 1}/{x(x + n)}
finding (positive) solutions for x, n always yielded z = 5. 
(z = - 3 occurs for negative integers x, y).

Comment: NOTE: for CASE 2, (positive integers) I did not prove that z = 5. Hence, this problem.  Completing this problem would in turn complete the other problem.

Comment: since $k= \frac{2a+b^2+b+1}{a(a+b)}$ we must have (i) $a$ divides $b^2+b+1$ and (ii) $a + b$ divides $2a+b^2+b+1$.  Performing polynomial long-division on (ii) implies $a + b$ divides $b(a + 1)-1$.